# What does 'Closed' mean for a question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work)

A recent question of mine was 'Closed' as 'not-programming-related'. I can't seem to find out what this means, and why this was (by browsing through) so here is the natural question!

(This time I'll flag it community wiki, to see if this is what I was supposed to do.)

Comment: It means no one can answer it. This is covered in the FAQ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127588/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work

Comment: Modded up for irony.

Comment: Great, thanks! I did try to find this answer/question in the FAQ, but my search was too broad (what would you search for?) and when I typed in the question, the one you refer to wasn't listed (at least not so I could see) in the related questions. So I went ahead.

I wasn't being ironic.

Comment: You don't need to wiki most questions in Meta.  (You're not supposed to be forced to in StackOverflow either, but the Community Wiki Police have staged the revolution and taken over).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[What is a “closed” question in Stackoverflow? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 2):

Questions asked on StackOverflow should be specifically about programming. If they're off-topic, they get closed, which means the question is basically 'locked' and no additional answers can be given for that question.